# Bootstrap 3 layout, involves combo of push/pull, a div "rowspan", and reordered divs for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I searched everywhere before posting, so sorry if it's a duplicate; nothing I found addressed my specific issue.

I need to have divs ordered differently between desktop and mobile using Bootstrap 3. Note: I could do it if I hardcoded everything, but I'm forced to use Bootstrap, and I know there is a solution that accommodates both desktop and mobile.

Here's the desktop layout. I can't figure out the combination of push/pull classes.

I tried moving the containing div for div 3 and div 4 to appear after div 1 and pull it over 6 columns, but div 1 disappears. I add a pull to div 1 and it's completely hidden from view. I added a clearfix to the containing row div with no success.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/WebDevJoshB/pen/qKeExj).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.row-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>4</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
</div><!--/.row-->
```

[image: Desktop Layout]

[image: Mobile Layout]

Will take a break and try later, but thought I'd post in meantime. /sigh

Comment: why not bootstrap 4?

Comment: I have to support IE9. I'm also coming into the middle of a project where it was set up with Bootstrap 3, and even if wanted to update to version 4 and set up polyfills, it would mean missing my deadline.